# Is there any way to highlight a file in the Visual Studio Code explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As a reminder, I would like to be able to highlight a file (in Explorer) that I have made important changes to. Highlighting it would make it easy to find again!

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: Version: 1.58.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code still doesn't provide such a feature. If you have source control, it will allow you to track modified files unless it is not available yet.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the files tracked with git are highlighted. I was expecting something like this to customize. Never mind

Comment: approve the answer if it helped.